# ReactJS - How to style a <td> tag when working with arrays?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a `Table` React component that renders the following table. This `Table` class receives a prop called `array` which let's say has 10 elements in it. So I am basically going through the `array` and adding every element to a new row. What I want to do is when a user clicks a particular button in the app, the column with id `foo` should turn yellow.

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
          <thead>
            <tr><th>Heading 1</th></tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.array.map(element =>
              <tr key={element}>
                <td id="foo">{element}</td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Right now, I am trying to do something like this:

```
class Bar extends React.Component {
  row;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.row = document.getElementById("foo");
  }

  render() {
    return {
      <button onClick={(event) => {
        this.update();
      }}>I will turn the #foo column yellow!
      </button>
    }
  }

  update() {
    this.row.classList.add('yellow-color');
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.yellow-color {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

However, it does not turn that column yellow. Does anyone know why this is the case? How do I go about with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I have noticed that when I add `className="yellow-color"` in the foo <td> tag, the column actually turns yellow like I want, so I think the problem is somewhere when I'm trying to get the element by id 'foo' and adding the class `yellow-color` using JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using document.getElementById() in React. You can achieve similar with [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), although it is not recommended.

You can achieve the same with using state and passing props.

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  state = {
    color: "black"
  };
  update = () => {
    this.setState({
      color: "yellow"
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={(event) => {
        this.update();
      }}>I will turn the #foo column yellow!
      </button>
      <table>
          <thead>
            <tr><th>Heading 1</th></tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.array.map(element =>
              <tr key={element}>
                <td style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }}>
                  {element}
                </td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```